# Hypothesis on / about

Tags: grammar

My virgin post!

Which has the most appropriate preposition usage of the following two sentences;

Do you have a hypothesis on why you got sick?
Do you have a hypothesis about how you got sick?

Or would you reformulate the sentence altogether?

Comment: Is your question about _on/about_ or on _how/why_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both prepositions are correct.

See some examples from Reverso.context.net:

Once we've determined the alkalinity of the soil, we can then begin to form a hypothesis **about** the local geology.

Experimental confirmation of the hypothesis on transphysical impact of art works ***on*** noosphere.